# Complete callback in AngularJS animation

Tags: javascript, animation, angularjs, callback

I have an AngularJS animation...

```
app.animation('slide-show', function () {
    return {
        setup: function (element) {
        },
        start: function (element, done) {
            element.slideDown(400, done);
        }
    };
} );

app.animation('slide-hide', function () {
    return {
        setup: function (element) {
        },
        start: function (element, done) {
            element.slideUp(400, done);
        }
    };
} );
```

I would like to be able to supply an additional "complete" callback as a parameter to the `start()` methods so that it can be invoked/passed to the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) methods. Is this somehow possible through the animation directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this question and this was how I achieved success:

I had the same setup for animation, but then I added an `ng-animated` property on the HTML element that I was animating, then I added the following:

```
app.animation('slide-show', function () {
    return {
        setup: function (element) {
        },
        start: function (element, done) {
            element.slideDown(400, function(){ 
                 var el = angular.element(element[0]);
                 el.scope().$eval(el.attr('ng-animated'));
                 done();
            });
        }
    };
} );

app.animation('slide-hide', function () {
    return {
        setup: function (element) {
        },
        start: function (element, done) {
            element.slideUp(400, function(){ 
                 var el = angular.element(element[0]);
                 el.scope().$eval(el.attr('ng-animated'));
                 done();
            });
        }
    };
} );
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 3):

You are already passing a "complete" callback (the second parameter to `element.slideUp()`), however you are not using your own but you simply call the `done` function Angular provides.

You must call that function eventually, but nothing keeps you from doing your own work beforehand.

```
app.animation('slide-hide', function () {
    return {
        setup: function (element) {
        },
        start: function (element, done) {
            element.slideUp(400, function () {
                // handle the end of the slideUp animation
                // ...

                // inform Angular that you're done
                done();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

---

You could generalize this, if you want:

```
function AnimationCallback(done, callback, callbackArgs) {
    return function () {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            // 'this' will be the DOM element that just finished animating
            callback.apply(this, callbackArgs);
        }
        done();
    }
}
```

and

```
app.animation('slide-hide', function () {
    return {
        setup: function (element) {
        },
        start: function (element, done) {
            element.slideUp(400, new AnimationCallback(done, yourCallback));
        }
    };
});
```

where `yourCallback` is any function you have defined and `callbackArgs` is an optional array of arguments that you'd like to pass to it.

Comment: Thanks for this, although I do not think it addresses the problem. Angular passes the done() method in order to be invoked to close off the animation (which is why I forward it to the jQuery methods). What I would like to do is somehow inject my own callback to the start() method. As the animation will be used as a directive (ng-animate="slide") your globally defined callback is not re-usable.

Comment: But you said *"I would like to be able to supply a "complete" callback"*, you did not say anything about `start`?

Answer (score 2):

```
app.animation('slide-show', function() {
    return {
        setup: function (element) {
            var complete = function() {
                /* Your implementation here */
            };

            return complete;
        },
        start: function (element, done, complete) {
            element.slideDown(400, done);

            /* Invoke the function and do something */
            complete();
        }
    };
});
```

For more details you may wanna checkout this article as well:

http://gsklee.im/post/50254705713/nganimate-your-angularjs-apps-with-css3-and-jquery#javascript-defined-animations

Comment: Unfortunately this solution isn't re-usable. I'm declaring my animation to be used globally throughout my application, which is why I want to be able to somehow pass in a complete callback. Defining the callback in the setup means it will apply to all uses of the animation which is not what I'm looking for.